# parameters in URL for query sorting

Tags: query-module

I'm using the query module to return entries for a particular page. I would like to create a drop down list where the user can change how the entries on those pages are sorted.

is it possible to use something like Mo' Variables to add something in the URL string that I can pick up and use in my query to change my sort on page refresh?

Something

www.site.com/category_name/?sort=rating_rank

I think I'm reaching for straws, so need some good guidance.

Answer (score 1):

sure, that is doable.
set your template to read php on input.
then in your query do

```
ORDER BY <?php echo ee()->input->get('sort'); ?>
```

or something like that

Comment: The "native" EE method would be using url segments like {segment_4}, of course ...

Comment: Mo' Variables also has variables set for GET parameters, so you could use those instead of using PHP in the template.